# Log command used to run the python script

Tags: python, linux, logging

I have a python Script (Ex : myscript.py) with some Options which i can launch from my terminal :

```
myscript -n name - a age
```

which will print in my terminal :

```
10/15/2021 10:47:57 AM [INFO] # Script launched
10/15/2021 10:47:58 AM [INFO] # Your Name : name, Your age : age
```

How can modify my script, in which way it will log also the command launched at the beginning, like add `logging.info("the command launched : {}.format(string_of_command)")` :

```
10/15/2021 10:47:57 AM [INFO] # Script launched
10/15/2021 10:47:57 AM [INFO] # command used : myscript -n name - a age 
10/15/2021 10:47:59 AM [INFO] # Your Name : name, Your age : age
```

Comment: "I want to modify my script" -> then do it, we dont know your code

Comment: Okay, and what exactly is preventing you from solving the problem yourself? What [have you tried](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) thus far? For example, did you try putting `python get command line` into a search engine? What happened when you did that?

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can use the `argv` variable of `sys` module using the code like below

```
print(f"{' '.join(sys.argv)}")
```

So in your case it would be like this

```
string_of_command = f"{' '.join(sys.argv)}"
logging.info("the command launched : {}.format(string_of_command)")
```

Comment: thanks for the hint, it gives the full path of the script.py also and options used, So I wil use some regex to keep only the useful part !

Comment: Can you try this one - os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]). And please accept the answer if this helps

Comment: the first answer was very helpful  already accepted your answer ;) thanks arnaud :)

Comment: you upvoted my answer there is accept icon just below the upvote then the answer will have a green tick. Glad it helped

Comment: Ah sorry , don't have the green tick yet !

Comment: cool, thanks. cheers